# Destructuring Syntax for Tuples?

Tags: dafny

So, I'm wondering whether there is any support for destructuring syntax in Dafny.  Something along the following lines:

```dafny
function method f(x:int) : (int,int) { (x,x+1) }

method test() {
    var y:int;
    var z:int;
    (y,z) := f(1);
}
```

In fact, I want to go further than this as I want to destructure within a `function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [reference manual](https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-case-pattern), you cannot do it for assignment statements, but only for variable declaration statements, like this:

```
function method f(x:int) : (int,int) { (x,x+1) }

method test() {
    var (y,z) := f(1);
}
```

If you want to annotate the types, you can do it like this:

```
var (y:int, z:int) := f(1);
```

You can also use a let expression to do this inside a function, like this:

```
function method f(x:int) : (int,int) { (x,x+1) }

function g() {
    var (y,z) := f(1);
    y+z
}
```

Comment: Thanks James --- that is actually enough for my use case :)